# How can I display all the users on my html page?

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

This piece of code gets me the required output in my python terminal

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

userList =User.objects.all()
print(userList)
```

**outputs this in the terminal**

```
<QuerySet [<User: brad>, <User: john>]>
```

I know I have to iterate through the QuerySet but I am not able to link this view to my main page.

So how can I get this on my main HTML page?

Answer (score 1):

In your `views.py` create `view` as

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserListView(ListView):

    model = User
    template_name = 'your_template_name.html'
```

Then in your `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from yourapp.views import UserListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('userlists', UserListView.as_view(), name='user-list'),
]
```

Then in your `html` loop through `object_list` as

```
<h1>User List</h1>
<ul>
{% for user in object_list %}
    <li>{{ user.username }}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No users yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: It displays an empty list.

Comment: Have you added `template_name` in your `views.py` in which you render data. See I have updated my answer. Change `your_template_name` by your template name

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudo code you can try,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    userList =User.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'users.html', {'users': userList})
```

And users.html like,

```
<h1>USERS</h1>
<ul>
{% for user in users %}
    <li>{{ user }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

urls.py is like,

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from app1.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: am I supposed to make changes in urls.py as well?

Comment: can you show urls.py ?

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home')]